# Compiling java class from command line defined in a package

Tags: java

I'm able to compile and run a simple hello world program from command line with

```java
javac hello.java
java hello
```

however, if I had a package statement at the top `package com.mypackage.myclass` and try the same I get

```
Error: Could not find or load main class Reflection
```

What is exactly happening? And how do I fix it? Thanks.

UPDATE: Thanks everyone. I already had created the directory structure manually. In order for this to work I have to run `java com.mypackage.myclass` from the root directory, otherwise it will not work. Still don't understand the underlying mechanism. What is exactly happening?

Comment: Do you have some other class in the same package?

Comment: Then you should enter `java com.mypackage.hello` and the class should be in the folder `com/mypackage/`

Comment: Did you defined a main class in hello.java?

Comment: @JavaTechnical OK, but what is exactly happening? How is java looking up for that class differently if it is defined in a package?

Comment: Package is wrt to Java. The JVM looks for a class with `com.mypackage` in `com/mypackage` folder. Defining a package doesn't itself create the directories, you need to manually create them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a java class like `com.example.test.Main` then the compiled class should be in a folder `com\example\test` and the class file name `Main.class`

You could manually do it, but compiler has a switch `-d <target folder>` which will create the folder structure for you.

```
javac -d . Main.java
```

In the above command the target folder is the current folder where you have the Java source file.

Once compiled you must use fully qualified name of the class to execute from the same folder you compiled the java file.

```
java com.example.test.Main
```

[Screen Cap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LsRAl.jpg)